How to handle collisions with coalesced balls?
Suppose there's a rail where balls can slide frictionless in a clockwise direction (positive speed) and counterclockwise direction (negative speed).
Computing the speeds after collision of ball B1 at -5cm/s and B2 at 5 cm/s is straightforward.
But how can I compute the speed of coalesced balls with different weights?
Say B1, B2 and B3, coalesced and are now sliding at -5 cm/s. Then, they collide with a coalesced group of B4, B5 that are sliding at 5 cm/s. Or a bigger group against a single one, etc.
To make it general, balls don't have the same weight. Otherwise, it's quite trivial.

Are you familiar with conservation of momentum?

Also, it's not clear whether when balls "coalesce" in your modelling of the problem, they become one big new ball or not. (If not, how exactly are they rolling as a group?)

Yes, I'm familair with conservation of linear momentum and kinetci energy, rolling resistance factor and restitution coefficient. I used them all  for simple collisions.  For the second comment, well, the balls are simply sliding exactly at the same speed. And the balls are separated exactly by their diameter.

Note that kinetic energy is generally not conserved for inelastic collisions, so one has to understand you're assuming no energy is lost in the process of coalescing? Secondly, it will help to answer your question if you also include how you tried to apply the conservation laws and the other details you mentioned.

By default, the motions of the balls are frictionless. The rolling resistance factor or the restitution factor can be used but, for this question, it's not used to keep things as simple as possible.

You solve the simple 2 ball case by figuring out the momentum and kinetic energy before the collision. Then you find the only possible velocities afterward that leave momentum and kinetic energy conserved.
You do the same for the multi ball case. The calculation is more complicated, but the method is the same.
